# executing exe using cmd or double click

Tags: windows, exe, cmd

I have an .exe which runs fine on double clicking but gives error on trying to run it using cmd. I am using Windows XP.

ANy suggestions why this may be so ?

Comment: if you want to execute any exe from command you just write a name of exe like `c:\>explorer`

Comment: Thanks Anant .. that what I am doing :) .. but it is not getting executed .. the bigger question I am trying to explore the answer for is - How double clicking is different from executing a an .exe in cmd. I know it should be fundamentally same, but still .. running in cmd says - " ***  has encountered a problem and needs to be closed"

Comment: Please provide all the relevant information for your question. Error messages, stack trace, code sample to reproduce.

Comment: OS??? Are you running it as admin???

Comment: It got resolved .. There were few dll dependencies .. When we double click on an .exe it looks for it in system variable and path settings .. but while trying to execute it in cmd .. it just looks for it in local directory .. I gave the dll path as command line argument and it worked .. thanks all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some programs are designed to not be launched from the command prompt.

You might be able to get around this by using `START.EXE` like so:

```
start program.exe
```

If that fails, try starting it with Windows Explorer like this:

```
explorer program.exe
```

Comment: This is especially also useful for opening a file with the so called "default application", so `explorer` for example also simulates a doubleclick for a `*.doc` file.